# MGLSymbolStyleLayer text not showing

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I successfully added an MGLSymbolStyleLayer layer to my map and configured its look by data from GeoJSON that's loaded locally, but I'm unable to set the value for text property.

This is how I'm trying to do it inside `mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle)` method:

```
customLayer.text = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "{name}")
```

When I run the app, the text is never shown while the image is loaded correctly. This is how my GeoJSON is formated.

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "name":"First name",
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               21.3,
               55.5
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "name":"Second name",
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               20.5,
               50.5
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you also opened [an issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/15475) in the `mapbox-gl-native` repo. Thank you for that. I responded there, but want to follow-up here as well.

It looks like you are trying to use feature interpolation (the `{}`). That should not be necessary for this use case. If you remove the curly braces, do you see the text?

`customLayer.text = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "name")`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It was an issue that `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` used by default a font that was not available on our server. Unfortunately, there were no 404 or any logs in Xcode console. It would be great if the SDK improved error logging for the styles. You can go ahead and close the GitHub issue. Also the above mentioned `NSExpression(forKeyPath: "name")` is correct.